# Summation notation to vector notation

Tags: vectors, index-notation

I've been working on computational fluid dynamics and have come across the following term in index notation:

$$\frac{\partial u_\mathrm{i}}{\partial x_\mathrm{m}}\frac{\partial u_\mathrm{j}}{\partial x_\mathrm{m}}$$

However, I'm having a hard time finding a vector notation equivalent to this operation. This is definitely not the inner product or outer product, but kind of like a "right" inner product. Has anyone come across any term like this and its vector notation equivalent?

To be more precise, I would like to know the operation $\odot$ in:

$$(\mathbf{\nabla}\otimes\mathbf{u})\odot(\mathbf{\nabla}\otimes\mathbf{u})$$

If one exists, or some other form. In the above, $\nabla \equiv \partial / \partial x_\mathrm{m}$, $\mathbf{u}$ is a Cartesian 3-vector, and $\otimes$ is the direct product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\nabla\otimes u$ is defined by $(\nabla\otimes u)_{im}:=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_m}$. The given expression is $(\nabla u)_{im}(\nabla\otimes u)_{jm}=(\nabla\otimes u(\nabla\otimes u)^T)_{ij}$, so the matrix we need is just $(\nabla\otimes u)(\nabla\otimes u)^T$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})^{T}$ is no longer a rank 2 matrix? Maybe I'm misinterpreting. It seems that $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})^{T}(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})$ may give me what I want.

Comment: @Doug Of course it's rank $2$. it's just ordinary matrix multiplication. But if you define the direct product as the transpose of what I used, the ${}^T$ will indeed move to the middle.